# C# multiple async tasks and where to properly await them when they use each other to complete?

Tags: c#, async-await

I have two methods that are similar, however, after theorizing about this, I'm pretty sure they are different in execution.

MethodOne:

```
        var renderDocumentDirective = await 
        RenderDocumentBuilder.Instance.GetRenderDocumentDirectiveAsync(previousPage, session);

        return await ResponseClient.Instance.BuildAlexaResponse(new Response()
        {
            shouldEndSession = null,
            directives = new List<IDirective>()
            {
                renderDocumentDirective
            }

        }, session.alexaSessionDisplayType);
```

MethodTwo

```
            var renderDocumentDirective = RenderDocumentBuilder.Instance.GetRenderDocumentDirectiveAsync(previousPage, session);
            return await ResponseClient.Instance.BuildAlexaResponse(new Response()
            {
                shouldEndSession = null,
                directives = new List<IDirective>()
                {
                    await renderDocumentDirective
                }

            }, session.alexaSessionDisplayType);
```

The first method uses the await operator on the async task, `RenderDocumentBuilder`, prior to its uses inside the `ResponseClient`, which is also an async task.

However the second method, sets up the Task `RenderDocumentBuilder`, but doesn't call the awaited method until it is inside the `ResponseClient`, which, at this point in execution, is waiting to return data.

Both ways of executing this method work, but I am unclear if it is proper to:

- await a task outside the ResponseClient? (method 1)
- Or, is it proper to create the renderDocumentDirective Task outside the ResponseClient and await it inside the method? (method 2)

Comment: I would argue that first one is cleaner and readable but unless `new Response()` calls have some strange side effects they are pretty much the same.

Comment: Would be interesting to see what IL they compile down to; I suspect the same thing. I'd echo Guru Stron in that the first one is more readable and the intention is clearer. Also, I think you can better handle any exceptions arising from `GetRenderDocumentDirectiveAsync` in the first example.

Comment: @GuruStron Why would the implementation of `ResponseClient.Instance` matter? The entire expression is evaluated before awaiting anyway.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay yep, agreed.

Comment: Do you mean it is evaluated before awaiting because it is a singleton instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you misinterpret the flow of data.

Here are your two methods written a bit more verbose

Method 1

```cs
var renderTask = RenderDocumentBuilder.Instance.GetRenderDocumentDirectiveAsync(previousPage, session);

var renderDocumentDirective = await renderTask;

var alexaResponse = new Response();

alexaResponse.shouldEndSession = null,
alexaResponse.directives = new List<IDirective>();
alexaResponse.directives.Add(renderDocumentDirective);

var buildTask = ResponseClient.Instance.BuildAlexaResponse(alexaResponse, session.alexaSessionDisplayType);

return await buildTask;
```

Method 2

```cs
var renderTask = RenderDocumentBuilder.Instance.GetRenderDocumentDirectiveAsync(previousPage, session);

var alexaResponse = new Response()
alexaResponse.shouldEndSession = null,
alexaResponse.directives = new List<IDirective>();
alexaResponse.directives.Add(await renderTask);

var buildTask = ResponseClient.Instance.BuildAlexaResponse(alexaResponse, session.alexaSessionDisplayType);

return await buildTask;
```

So you see that the only real difference is that methode 2 creates the `Response` object, sets `shouldEndSession` and creates the `List` object before or it awaits the `renderTask`.

Method 2 might be beneficial, but this depends on how `GetRenderDocumentDirectiveAsync` is implemented (i.e. truely async). But even if it is, it is highly unlikly that method 2 brings any performance gains as there is not much difference between both methods.

That said, I would go with method 1, because it looks more like sync code and in most cases you want to await a Task as soon you have it available, because await/async is mainly about freeing threads to do other stuff and not about parallalism.